# How to receive notifications from Firebase in window's context (as well as service worker)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have a react app with the following in firebase-messaging-sw.js in public folder of the app:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': '<my-sender-id>'
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Do some stuff
});
```

And in my index.js file I have this:

```
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
    console.log( registration);

    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.

      } else {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
      }
    });


  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
  });
}
```

I can publish a message and get a notification if the window is not active. So far, so good.

However, I also need to get the notification if the window is active. I try adding this to the service worker:

```
// Handle incoming messages. Called when:
// - a message is received while the app has focus
// - the user clicks on an app notification created by a service worker
//   `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler` handler.
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  // ...
});
```

...but I get this error from firebase:
    `errors.ts:101 Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available     in a Window context. (messaging/only-available-in-window).`

It seems that the above javascript needs to go into the index.js file so that it is processed in the window context (all of the questions I have seen on this just say "the onMessage call need to be in the foreground app").

BUT then I don't have access to the messaging variable declared in the service worker.

Whats the correct way to do this? Surely I shouldn't be initialising firebase twice?

Answer (score 1):

Only the `setBackgroundMessageHandler()`-method must be called in the serviceworker.

You need to use the `onMessage()` handler in the javascript-files of your Application-UI to do further actions with the payload.

Take a close look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive).