# JS/Firebase - messaging.onBackgroundMessage is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my whole code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.16.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.16.0/firebase-messaging.js";
//This data is filled correctly just clearing it here for the question
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "t",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const bbFirebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging();
// Add the public key generated from the console here.
getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'I_HAVE_PLACED_VALID_KEY_HERE' }).then((currentToken) => {
    if (currentToken) {
        console.log("TOKEN: " + currentToken);
    } else {
        // Show permission request UI
        console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        // ...
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    // ...
});

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body:  payload.notification.body,
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
function requestPermission() {
    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
            console.log('Notification permission granted.');
            // TODO(developer): Retrieve a registration token for use with FCM.
            // In many cases once an app has been granted notification permission,
            // it should update its UI reflecting this.
            resetUI();
        } else {
            console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
        }
    });
}
```

So when I execute this code I can generate a token. I see the token clearly and all good there. However I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: messaging.onBackgroundMessage is not a function
> at firebase.js:31:11

Any idea why I can this error and how can I at least `console.log()` print the incoming notifications?

Answer (score 1):

The `onBackgroundMessage()` is a top level function just like `getToken()` in the new functional syntax imported from `firebase/messaging/sw` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_service_worker).

```
import { getMessaging, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging'
import { onBackgroundMessage } from 'firebase/messaging/sw'

onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: When I do that it gives this error " This method is available in a service worker context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw).
    at onBackgroundMessage.ts:36:13 "

Comment: @Venelin that's correct. Why are you using background message if you want to run it on web itself?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean.

Comment: Are you using a service worker/PWA? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62283748/13130697

Comment: When I do that I get this error: `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler is not a function at firebase-messaging-sw.js:22:11`

Comment: The code of firebase-messaging-sw.js: https://gist.github.com/48184fd6cea7e02439d42e1aaf8561f8

Comment: No, don't use the old syntax code. My question is, why not use `onMessage()` instead of `onBackgroundMessage` with the syntax in my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251525/discussion-between-venelin-and-dharmaraj).

Answer (score 1):

I´m having trouble with this too but if you paste this code in firebase-messaging-sw.js and that file is in the root of firebase hosting it works.

```
// Import and configure the Firebase SDK
// These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting
// If you do not serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
importScripts('/__/firebase/9.2.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

/**
 * Here is is the code snippet to initialize Firebase Messaging in the Service
 * Worker when your app is not hosted on Firebase Hosting.

 // Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
 // Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here. Other Firebase libraries
 // are not available in the service worker.
 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

 // Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
 // your app's Firebase config object.
 // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
 firebase.initializeApp({
   apiKey: 'api-key',
   authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
   databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
   projectId: 'project-id',
   storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
   messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
   appId: 'app-id',
   measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
 });

 // Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
 // messages.
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();
 **/


// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// Keep in mind that FCM will still show notification messages automatically 
// and you should use data messages for custom notifications.
// For more info see: 
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
//   console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] PAYLOAD NOTIFICATION: ', payload.notification);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: payload.notification.image
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```